# Error in creating airflow connection: fails with incorrect padding issue

Tags: airflow

When I try to create connection (SSH) in Airflow with username and password it fails an error like below

"Failed to update record. Could not create Fernet object: Incorrect padding"

[image: Error screenshot is below]

Comment: did you set FERNET_KEY env variable ? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html#fernet

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I didn't have the fernet_key set before.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set fernet key in airflow.cfg or as env variable:

```
export AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=your_fernet_key
```

See [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html#fernet) for more information.